# App get closes before the running the full espresso test

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-espresso

I am writing a test case with espresso for my Registration screen, I have one field in my screen where when user tap opens another activity(i.e LocationActivity) which contains Google Autocomplete edit-text, once user select suggested place from given list user get navigate back to Register screen and based on his/her selection postal code, suburb and State get filled and the user has to tap on Submit button to hit an API.

Here is the code regarding my test:

```
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

import com.ansible.racq.Activity.RegisterDetailActivity;
import com.ansible.racq.Util.Constants;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.RootMatchers.withDecorView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;

@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class RegisterDetailActivityTest {
    private String mFirstname, mLastname,mLearnerLicenseNumber,mMobileNumber,mStreetAddress;
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<RegisterDetailActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(RegisterDetailActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void prepareData() {
        mFirstname = "siddharth";
        mLastname = "khindri";
        mLearnerLicenseNumber="123456789";
        mMobileNumber="8600032384";
        mStreetAddress="sebiz square master software solutions";
    }

    @Test
    public void registerDetailActivityTest() {
        // Added a sleep statement to match the app's execution delay.
        // The recommended way to handle such scenarios is to use Espresso idling resources:
        // https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/idling-resource/index.html
        try {
            onView(withId(R.id.et_first_name)).perform(typeText(mFirstname), closeSoftKeyboard());
            onView(withId(R.id.et_last_name)).perform(typeText(mLastname), closeSoftKeyboard());
            onView(withId(R.id.et_learner_number)).perform(typeText(mLearnerLicenseNumber), closeSoftKeyboard());
            onView(withId(R.id.et_mobile_number)).perform(typeText(mMobileNumber), closeSoftKeyboard());
            onView(withId(R.id.et_street)).perform(typeText(mStreetAddress), closeSoftKeyboard());
            onView(withId(R.id.et_suburb)).perform(click());
            Thread.sleep(Constants.ONE_SEC_DELAY);
            onView(withId(R.id.et_search_location))
                    .perform(typeText("canberra"), closeSoftKeyboard());
            onView(withText("canberra ACT"))
                    .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
                    .perform(click());
            Thread.sleep(Constants.THREE_SEC_DELAY);
            onView(withId(R.id.btn_register)).perform(click());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is whenever the user gets to navigate to Google autocomplete screen the application get close with Test pass notification, How can I make application to come back on register screen and the perform click on Register button?

Can one help me out in this?

Regards